# Add selection animation to a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton, touch-up-inside

I have a UIButton in one of my ViewControllers with three different state images (normal, highlighted and selected). When I press this button, it becomes highlighted and when I release it, selected. I want to make an animation that changes the highlighted image of the button to the selected one in 4 seconds with a fadeIn or so.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

Try `UIView transitionWithView` by setting first the **normal** and **selected** images to `UIButton`, and then in the action handler animate the change:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.addListButton
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    [self.addListButton setSelected:YES];
                } completion:nil];
```

I didn't want to change the state of the `UIButton` so I just changed the **normal** image in the animation block:

```
[self.addListButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-addbutton.png"]
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to enroll your own `UIButton` subclass and you'll probably have to overwrite `setSelected` and `setHighlighted` with your custom animation code. The safer bet would be to subclass `UIControl` directly and reimplement those selectors so that you don't have any `UIButton` specific legacy.